# UITableViewCell circle imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I have an `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell` and I want to make `cell.imageView`as circles. So I did this in my `cellForrowAtIndex`

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];




    }

    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius=cell.imageView.frame.size.width/2;
    cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds=YES;
    cell.imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
    cell.imageView.layer.borderColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
```

But when load the table `UIImage`s are squares and then when I scroll it become circles. How can I solve this problem? 
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a custom cell by inheriting `UITableViewCell` and then configure cell in that class.

Implement `awakeFromNib` method in it and set your image view as you need in this method.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code

```
[cell.imgview setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:imgData]];
cell.imgview.layer.cornerRadius = cell.img_userpic.frame.size.height /2;
cell.imgview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
cell.imgview.layer.borderWidth = 0;
```

Your Imageview's width and height should be same otherwise it won't display circle.

Answer (score 0):

Use below line of code in your cellForRow Method. For circle you have to set cornerradius of layer and set clipsToBounds property to `YES`.

```
  cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: no its still same,, when load all squares when scroll only they become circles

Comment: Have wrote that `cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES`; in cellfor Row method?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-30, 40, 100, 100)];
        imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
        imageView.layer.shadowRadius=5;
        imageView.layer.shadowOpacity=4;
        imageView.layer.shadowColor=(__bridge CGColorRef)([UIColor blackColor]);
        imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
        imageView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
        imageView.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;
        imageView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
        imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```